# show invalid characters in Pycharm

Tags: unicode, pycharm

show invalid characters for non-English characters(eg:Sinhala).

This my string "එය උත්සාහ කර බැලීමට, පහත දැක්වෙන ඔබභාෂාව සහ ආදාන මෙවලම් තෝරා ටයිප් කිරීම අරඹන්න."

but it show in pycharm look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdtcr.jpg).

I've already tried all the solutions google proposed for fixing this issue for java files, such as:

"Settings->Editor->File Encodings" has both "IDE Encoding" and "Project Encoding" as UTF-8.

please help..

Comment: You should upload your code and error in more detail.

Comment: any one help me

Comment: What happens when you install a Singhalese font, e.g. [Noto Sans Sinhala](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-sinh), and restart Pycharm?

Comment: Could you copy again the string, maybe from this site (so your post) to pycharm? I did it im my Pycharm, and I see the correct text. It doesn't seem a problem of font, but just that you copied a non-UTF-8 into the sources, an somehow it get later transformed to UTF-8 with the wrong symbols